# Compress all nested subdirectorires recursively in batch

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have a folder with the following structure:

```
Year
    Month
        Day
            file
            file
            file
        Day 
            file
            file
Year
    Month
        Day
            file
            file
            file
        Day 
            file
            file
```

and I want to compress all the "Day" folders in place to later move them.

So far I've tried a few alternatives I found here on SO but I cant seem to get the result I need and I cant even get past the syntax errors on my own attempt. This is what I have so far:

```
for /d %%A in (C:\test) do
    for /d %%B in (C:\test\*) do 
        for /d %%C in (C:\test\*\*) do
            "C:\Program Files\WinRAR\rar.exe" a -r -u -rr
```

Comment: You can put `if`s in your for loops like `if %%A EQU "Day" ("C:\Program Files\WinRAR\rar.exe" a -r -u -rr )`

Comment: Can I put a wild card in there? All the days are numbers.

Comment: Unfortunately, no, but you can make a for loop with `(C:\test\day*)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Wildcards](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-wildcards.html) are only allowed in the last element of a path, so something like `C:\test\*\*` is not going to work.

Anyway, you are quite close to the solution:

```cmd
for /D %%Y in ("C:\test\*") do (
    for /D %%M in ("%%~Y\*") do (
        for /D %%D in ("%%~M\*") do (
            pushd "%%~D" && (
                rar a -r -u -rr "..\%%~nD.rar" "*.*"
                popd
            )
        )
    )
)
```

You just forgot to continue the loop body on the same line as the `do` keyword (note the opening `(` on the same line here), and you missed to use the [`for` loop](https://ss64.com/nt/for_d.html) meta-variables of the outer loops within the inner ones.

This should create `.rar` archive files named by `Day` and located in the `Month` folders. If you want them put into the `Day` folders instead, just remove the `..\` prefix from `..\%%~nD.rar" "*.*`.

[`pushd`](https://ss64.com/nt/pushd.html) and [`popd`](https://ss64.com/nt/popd.html) are used to temporarily change into the current `Day` directory, so the archive contains paths relative to that one rather than to the root or something.

Comment: I dont think this worked as intended. What it did was create one rar file with year1 and all the contents of the parent folder, then another file called year2 with the contents of the parent folder, including the previous rar and so on. I need to rar the folders titled "day" in place

Comment: Well, not sure if I got that right, but you maybe want to change the `rar` command line to `rar a -r -u -rr "%%~D\%~nD.rar" "*.*"`. Anyway, my goal was mainly to demonstrate how to correctly set up the nested loops…

Comment: @aschipfl, should it not be `for /D %%M in ("%%~Y\*") do (
        for /D %%D in ("%%~M\*")`?

Comment: To explain @dominique120, Let's say that the `Year` directories were located in `C:\test`, using `For /D %%A In (C:\test\*) Do …` would return those individual year directories like this, `C:\test\2014`, as `%%A`. If you then nest a second `For /D` in the same format, you'll retrieve each `Month` directory in each `Year` directory, `For /D %%A In ("C:\test\*") Do For /D %%B In ("%%~A\*") Do …` would return, e.g. `C:\test\2014\11` as `%%B`. Taking it another step will retrieve the `Day` directories, `For /D %%A In ("C:\test\*") Do For /D %%B In ("%%~A\*") Do For /D %%C In ("%%~B\*") Do …`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation @Compo its much clear now! However it seems like the solution is putting the files in the right place but for some reason its compressing the entire root directory. Could it be winrar getting a wrong parameter for the directory? All the files in the "day" folder are numbers. Could I use a wildcard to tell winrar to compress all folders in the directory that have a number in their name? Or something similar to avoid this issue.

Comment: In the `rar` command line, replacing `"*.*"` by `"%%~D\*.*"` should do it. Where should the `*.rar` files be put – inside the respective Day folder?

Comment: I would think, taking my commented example above, @dominique120, that you'd want to use `rar a -r -u -rr "%%~B\%%~nxC.rar" "%%~C\*"` as your command. That is to add, and update, with an auto size recovery record, all files and subdirectories of your day directories to a RAR archive named the same name as the day, and located in the month directories. For the answer above, I'd expect that to be `rar a -r -u -rr "%%~M\%%~nxD.rar" "%%~D\*"`.

Comment: This solution worked well, thanks. One final question though: What I cant test if the file exists with  an if statement? when I put ```if exists "..\%%~nD.rar" (rar command)``` I get an error saying that ```..\%%~nD.rar``` was not expected. How can I test if the file already exists?

Comment: @dominique120, to start with, the command you should be using is `If Exist`, not `If Exists`! Please also note that whilst we're happy to assist, questions are supposed to be one per post. One a person, or persons, have assisted you to solve your initially posted issue, they haven't signed up to a future support roll with you. Asking more questions under the umberella of another colud be potentially detrimental to your future experience here.